# use Java Swing worker as a singleton to backup application data in the background

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I plan to use Java SwingWorker as a singleton to backup application data in the background periodically(perhaps in combination with a Swing timer or java.util.Timer) 
is such a strategy sound?  is applying Singleton to SwingWorker a good idea?

Comment: be sure that for periodical BackUp of Aplications data is your idea correct, this way you sepatate aplications logics from GUI to the Background tasks, that to avoid to freeze your GUI during hardiest and longiest tasks, for your idea is there anothet options by using java.util.Timer

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what `SwingWorker` has to do with a backup task.  I don't see either what the singleton pattern has to do with.  This is a task for a `Timer`.  You might have to be careful not to start it in multiple threads however, but that should be doable without wrapping it as a singleton.

Comment: I use SwingWorker because it deals with reading gui states, I also plan to do recovery which will definitely manipulate gui states, should I use SwingWorker definitely for the recovery then?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could easily use the `SwingWorker` for saving the state of your model. If you want to do this task in the background preferably would be to make a current copy of your state and save the copy thus you do not need to worry about synchronizing the state of the model while you are saving it in another thread.

Where it goes to recovery you probably want to make sure that user will not make and later loose all that he did during the model recovery from a previous version. As on successful recovery you probably will set the current state to it. Thus in this case it is even appropriate to block any user input thus you can easily do it on the current thread. Firstly displaying some appropriate information/dialog to you user that the state is being recovered.